# Медленно работает PC-BSD в Virtualbox

Tags: freebsd, virtualbox

Возникла такая проблема, очень медленно работает PC-BSD (с KDE) на Virtualbox (Win 7 Pro x64 ), то есть открытие каждого меню происходит с задержкой секунд в 5-10, Virtualbox и PC-BSD последних версий, но и раньше была аналогичная проблема, стоит на SSD + 8Gb RAM (на хосте CPU Q9650 / RAM 16Gb)

Comment: Проверьте включена ли аппаратная виртуализация в BIOS и в самом Virtualbox.

Comment: проверю конечно, но была включена, да и тот же Linux работает вполне себе быстро